# Create new App ID for In-App Purchase in Developer Portal

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Do I need to create a new APP ID for my first In-App Purchase through the developer portal?  I already have a App ID for my original application, but want to launch my first In-App application, but I keep reading I need to create a new App ID, but does that mean I do it under the developer portal and get a new provisioning profile also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you don't.** New appid means new app. You only need a **NEW VERSION**.

Simply go to your app settings add a **New Version** in iTunes Connect after that press In-App Purchase button.

- Press New In-App Purchase button
- Select type (Consumable, non-Consumable, etc.)
- Add reference name (title) and product id (based on your bundle id)
- Select pricing
- Upload screenshot (user interface with the IAP button is fine)

I recommend using MKStorekit framework, it's well done and maintained.

You need separate (non-widlcard) development and distribution profiles for the app based on its bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a specific App ID. Yours would be similar to com.MikeFlynn.App. After, create another provisioning profile for this App ID and install it on both your computer and iOS devices. Lastly, create the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect for the app that is using the App ID you just created.